# geometric model of J-homomorphism

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I worry that this question may be an expression of my sorely lacking knowledge of classical topology, but here it goes.

Let $ku$ be the connective cover of complex K-theory and $pic(S)$ the spectrum classifying spherical fibrations. "Taking Thom spaces" produces a map $T: ku \to Pic(S)$. I view this as an (infinite loop) map of infinite loop spaces. Taking loops, we arrive at: $$\Omega T: \Omega ku \to \Omega Pic(S) = S^\times.$$ Now my favourite models of these spaces are $\Omega ku = U$ (the infinite unitary group) and $S^\times \subset (\coprod_n B \Sigma_n)'$, where the prime denotes group completion.

**Question:** Can I produce the map $U \to (\coprod_n B \Sigma_n)'$ directly/geometrically, i.e. without first knowing that the right hand side is the units of the stable sphere?

Comment: It is slightly unclear (to me) what you mean by your model of $S^\times$. The space $(\coprod_n B\Sigma_n)'$ is equivalent to $Q(S^0)$. If I am not mistaken, $S^\times$ is equivalent to $Q_{\pm 1}(S^0)$ - the union of two path components of this space. The intersection of $S^\times$ and $\coprod_n B\Sigma_n$ in $Q(S^0)$ consists of one point ($B\Sigma_1$), which perhaps suggests that $(\coprod_n B\Sigma_n)'$ is not a good model for $S^\times$... (cont.)

Comment: I wonder about the following variant of the question: think of $Q(S^0)$ as ${\mathbb Z}\times B\Sigma_\infty^+$ (this is Quillen's plus construction), and ask if there is a way to produce a map $U\to B\Sigma_\infty^+$, or even $SO\to B\Sigma_\infty^+$ without using the connection of the right hand side to the sphere spectrum.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow. As you say $S^\times$ is a subspace of "my favourite model", and hence if you can map into $S^\times$ you can also map into my space? But I think for the context of this question the equivalence between my space and $\mathbb{Z} \times B\Sigma^+_\infty$ is "elementary", so this alternative model is fine too.

Comment: The original constructuion of such map $U\to SG=Q_{1}S^0$ is induced by one point compatification of a unitary transformation which seems enough geometric to me. If you wish to produce a map into the group completion of the monoid associated to the infinite symmetric group then I think you will need to consider representstion theory which seems less geometric to me.

Comment: I don't believe that any straightforward combination of known ideas can produce such a map directly; it would need a significantly new technique.